# 'We put new carpet on the floor or we put [a] new carpet on the floor'?

Tags: sentence-construction, articles, singular-vs-plural, spoken-english

I wonder should I precede the noun with the article 'a', but I don't think that is necessary?

> I put [a] new carpet on the floor.

Reason: Carpet is a mass noun.

---

Am I correct?

Comment: "A new carpet" is fine. How is it a mass noun?

Comment: I referred to (https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/carpet)

Comment: @user178049 When used as a mass noun, *carpet* has the same meaning as *carpeting*.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what kind of carpet you mean.

If you put “**a** carpet” on the floor, I would interpret that to mean “a rug”: A thing that's laid out on the floor, on top of another floor covering, without being permanently attached to it.

[image: Rug]

If, however, the carpet is permanently attached to the floor, especially if it fills its room “wall-to-wall”, then that's the mass noun “carpet” (no article).

Comment: That solved my query!

Comment: I disagree that one can only use an article with a piece of carpet. I have **a** wall-to-wall ("fitted") carpet in each of the rooms of my house, except the kitchen and bathroom.